# Check if data connection is "ticked"

Tags: android, 3g

I'm building an android application that will use a Switch widget to enable/disable the data connection of the device.

My problem is actually the data roaming: if the user has disabled the data connection roaming, then the API methods such `NetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()` or `TelephoneManager.getDataState()` will say that the connection is off.

In general this is true, but in my context this is false *if the data connection is "ticked" from the android settings*.

So, I need a method that can check if the data connection is ticked, instead of enabled/active/etc.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define "mobile_data" row name, where the system stores the data connection checkbox/switch's state, locally:

```
private static final String MOBILE_DATA = "mobile_data";
```

And check if the value of that row is `0` or not. If it is `0`, then the data connection is unchecked/disabled (un-ticked):

```
private boolean isMobileDataChecked() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        // The row has been moved to 'global' table in API level 17
        return Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), MOBILE_DATA, 0) != 0;
    }

    try {
        // It was in 'secure' table before
        int enabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), MOBILE_DATA);
        return enabled != 0;
    } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        // It was in 'system' table originally, but I don't remember when that was the case.
        // So, probably, you won't need all these try/catches.
        // But, hey, it is better to be safe than sorry :)
        return Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), MOBILE_DATA, 0) != 0;
    }
}
```